# order list of Lat long vertices to form a polygon in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, polygons, non-convex

I have list of Lat long that form a polygon around a center point. I would like to get ordered List of Lat-Long clockwise so as to  connect Lat-Long Vertices in that ordered list and form non-convex polygon.

Comment: StackOverflow is not *I want that, give me code* site. What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I m trying to understand how set of Lat and Long as a list of points can be used to form polygon. what are possible ways to solve this ?

Answer (score 2):

The generation of a polygon from a set of vertices is ill-defined, as can be seen in the following example.

Let

```
A = ( 0, 0)
B = ( 3,-3)
C = ( 6,-1)
D = ( 4,-1)
E = ( 4, 1)
F = ( 6, 1)
G = ( 3, 3)
```

One possibility to form a polygon clockwise is

`A-G-F-E-D-C-B-A`

and the ordering

`A-G-E-F-C-D-B-A`

is a different one. The first polygon is concave and the second aon is convex. If `A` is removed and the remaining points are mirrored at the axis `G-B`, it is even possible to define two non-convex polygons from the given set of vertices. More precisely,
the set of vertices would be

```
B = ( 3,-3)
C = ( 6,-1)
D = ( 4,-1)
E = ( 4, 1)
F = ( 6, 1)
G = ( 3, 3)

E' = ( 2, 1)
F' = ( 0, 1)
D' = ( 2,-1)
C' = ( 0,-1)
```

and the two different polygons are

`G-E-F-C-D-B-C'-D'-E'-F'-G`

and

`G-F-E-D-C-B-D'-C'-F'-E'-G`.

However, if one ins interested in the convex hull polygon (the boundary of the convex hull) of the given vertices, there are many different [algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms) to compute it.

Comment: or in simple words, as anyone that tried to solve a connect-the-dot puzzle as a kid - to draw a poligon, the order of the dots is critical.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Thanks for the straightforward reformulation. However I wanted to provide a specific example which has few vertices, covers all cases and uses only non-intersecting edges.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I would like to know how would this apply when these vertices are defined with spatial co-ordinates(lat/long) ?

Comment: @user1701450 I don't understand your comment, in the example above the vertices _are_ given with spatial coordinates - or do you mean something different?

Comment: I mean I have set of lat n long coordinates and  I am ordering it. can you please provide some pseudo code to implement the approach you explained above and order the points when joined form closed polygon ?